# mysql select statement not returning rows where some tables in query aren't populated

Tags: mysql

I'm having a real mind blank - This code selects rows quite nicely apart from those entries where I change st.station_id from a value of '1' to a different (but still valid) number but where there are no entries for that station_id in either the station_owner_map table, the organisation table or the cap_gen_data_table. I basically need to amend my sql to ignore any table where there are no entries.

```
Select st.station_id, st.station_name , st.st_town, st.st_state, c1.country_name,   o1.organisation_name, som1.equity, st.river_basin, st.cost, st.cost_ref, st.comm_year,cg1.caporgen, ht1.hydro_name, cg1.value, srs1.srs_description, cg1.ref_year
FROM station st
inner join station_country_map scm1 on st.station_id = scm1.station_id
inner join country c1 on scm1.country_id = c1.country_id
inner join station_owner_map som1 on st.station_id = som1.station_id
inner join organisation o1 on som1.owner_id = o1.org_id
inner join cap_gen_data cg1 on st.station_id = cg1.station_id
inner join value_lookup vl1 on cg1.caporgen = vl1.id
inner join hydro_type ht1 on cg1.hydro_type_id = ht1.type_id
inner join station_record_status srs1 on cg1.capacity_status = srs1.st_rec_stat_id
where st.station_id = 1
```

Comment: +1 for constructing your query in such a way that meant this was a doddle to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left` join on tables where the value may not be present.

If you have two tables `A` and `B` an inner join will only return the rows from `A` where the join condition is met.  A `left` join will return all rows from `A` regardless of if the join condition is satisfied.  Columns in the select statement associated with `B` will be null when a left join is used.

I have only added the `left join` to the tables you have indicated.  If other tables may not satisfy the join condition change the join type from `inner` to `left`.

```
Select st.station_id, st.station_name , st.st_town, st.st_state, c1.country_name,   o1.organisation_name, som1.equity, st.river_basin, st.cost, st.cost_ref, st.comm_year,cg1.caporgen, ht1.hydro_name, cg1.value, srs1.srs_description, cg1.ref_year
FROM station st
inner join station_country_map scm1 on st.station_id = scm1.station_id
inner join country c1 on scm1.country_id = c1.country_id
left join station_owner_map som1 on st.station_id = som1.station_id
left join organisation o1 on som1.owner_id = o1.org_id
left join cap_gen_data cg1 on st.station_id = cg1.station_id
inner join value_lookup vl1 on cg1.caporgen = vl1.id
inner join hydro_type ht1 on cg1.hydro_type_id = ht1.type_id
inner join station_record_status srs1 on cg1.capacity_status = srs1.st_rec_stat_id
where st.station_id = 1
```

Comment: why remove the where clause? it refers to the primary table of the query, so will still allow left joins. this answer is actually wrong now that you've removed the where clause.

Comment: @Bohemian I may be reading the question wrong, I thought he wanted to get other stations in the same result set.

Comment: first line: *... station_id from a value of '1' ...*

Comment: @Kevin -I c + p'd your answer in but alas its not correct...  both of these .. 'organisation o1 on som1.owner_id = o1.org_id could be null and and those values which could be in the 'cap_gen_data' table could also be null - sorry was too quick on the save

Comment: @user2606469 What isn't correct about it?  Are you sure the other tables have values?  They may need left joined also.  As I state in my answer I took your word on only those three tables having missing data.

Comment: @kevin - There are very few rows in the database as I'm still building the whole thing. There are precisely seven stations and less rows in the other tables and none for the station_ids causing me problems in the tables I mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @user2606469 Did you try just adding the left join to everything?

Comment: @kevin - yes tried that too. I'm pretty sure the row I need to do something about is the 5th row as there could be no relevant data for this selection in either the station_owner_map table or the organisation table. All other rows will have at least a value in one or the other tables as they are either data tables or lookups.

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion - I've worked it out @kevin - I must have tried some other mix of left joins as you suggestion about changing to left joins now works and gives me what I'm after. I'm sure I tried it but anyway. It now brings back all my expected rows: code is ....

Answer (score 2):

It's caused by your `inner join`s. `Inner join` means there has to be a value in both tables for the record to show up in the result set.

Use `left join` instead, then only the table 'on the left' has to have a value.

Comment: @Sebastian - The problem is though that in line 5 there is potentially no entry in either table which is where I think the crux of the problem is. I've played around with left joins as advised by others but there is no potential saving left join in this line: inner join organisation o1 on som1.owner_id = o1.org_id